# Prove that formula is not tautology in intuitionistical logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

$$(p\to q)\Leftrightarrow (\neg p \vee q)$$.
I consider only $$(p\to q)\to(\neg p \vee q)$$
$w_0\vdash$
$w_1\vdash p$
$w_2\vdash q$
Then we can also say that :
$w_0\vdash \not \neg p$  in other words $w_0\not\vdash \neg p$
$w_1\vdash \not \neg q$  in other words $w_1\not\vdash \neg q$
Moreover, I should add:
$w_1\vdash \not q$
$w_2\vdash \not p$

Now, lets conclude:
$w_0\not\vdash q,p\neg q, \neg p$
$w_1\not\vdash (\neg p\vee q), (p\to q)$
$w_2\vdash (\neg p\vee q), (p\to q)$
Because $w_0\not\vdash (\neg p\vee q)$ and $w_1\vdash (p\to q)$ so $w_0\not\vdash (p\to q)\to(\neg p \vee q)$.

1. Is it ok ?
2. Is it true that $w\vdash \not p$ is the same as $w\not\vdash p$ ?
3. Am I right that determining for each state which variable (here $p,q$) one of the possibility: $p,\not p, q,\not q$ is in my hands ( I try to find counterexample) ?.  Of course choice of these possibility give us following additional information:
   For example if I decide that $w_0\vdash p$ then I can say that $w_0\not \vdash\neg p$.  Similary, If I decide that $w\vdash \neg p$  then I can say that $w\not\vdash p$.  Generally, play in deciding about $p,q$ is aimed to find a counterexample.
   Yeah ?

Comment: A kripke model is a partial order, not a total order.  So when you specify one, you also have to say what the order is.  For example, it could be the case that $w_1 \le w_2$, or that $w_2 \le w_1$, or neither could be true.

Comment: Ok, so $w_0\le w_1$ and $w_0\le w_2$. Try to answer my quesions, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment* : it seems to me that there are some typos in your proof.

Assuming that : $w_0 \le w_1,w_2$, with the model :

> $w_0 \nVdash p,q \ , w_1 \Vdash p \ , w_2 \Vdash q$

we have :

> $w_0 \nVdash (¬p∨q)$

and also : $w_1 \nVdash (p→q)$ because it is not true that for every $w \ge w_1$ if $w \Vdash p$, then $w \Vdash q$ : consider $w_1$ itself.

But  : $w_2 \Vdash (p→q),(¬p∨q)$; why $w_2 \Vdash (p→q)$ ? Because $w_2 \nVdash p$ and thus the conditional holds vacuously.

If so, also $w_0 \nVdash p$ and thus also $w_0 \Vdash (p→q)$.

So, it seems to me, the counter-example works, because of :

> > $w_0 \Vdash (p→q)$ and $w_0 \nVdash (¬p∨q)$.

---

*Note.* I'm not very skilled in the art of conjuring Kripke countermodels...

If the above counterexample works, then it seems to me that a single-node model $w_0$ that forces neither $p$ nor $q$ (and thus $w_0 \nVdash (\lnot p \lor q)$) will suffice, becuse vacuously : $w_0 \Vdash (p \to q)$.

Comment: Tell me one thing: If someone write only $w\vdash p$ it is ok to asume that this guy assume that $w\not \vdash  q$ (because he wroty only information about $p$)

Comment: @HaskellFun - yes; with $w \Vdash p$ we specify that the atom $p$ is "forced by" $w$. The "not specified" atoms are not forced. What is not correct (we are working in intuitionistic logic) is to move from $w \nVdash p$ to $w \Vdash \lnot p$.

Comment: for me, $w_0\not\vdash p\to q$. After all, in other case it should be also that $w_1\vdash p\to q$.

Comment: $w_2 \Vdash (p \to q)$ because $w_2\Vdash q$. However, $w_1\not\Vdash (p\to q)$ because $w_1\Vdash  p$ and $w_1\not\Vdash q$